# Cannot initialize in child the field defined in parent

Tags: java, oop

How to define field in parent class and assign value in child to this field so it will be accessible for type `Room`? I think this `int bound = 3;` will hide parent variable...

```
public abstract class Room {public int bound; }

public class DarkRoom extends Room {

     bound = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the field in the constructor, not in the class declaration:

```
public class DarkRoom extends Room {
    public DarkRoom() {
        bound = 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class initialization block:

```
public class DarkRoom extends Room {
   {
     bound = 3; // error VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token
         // int bound = 3; // hiding?
    }
}
```

or perform the initialization in a method or a constructor of the `DarkRoom` class.

Comment: Why use an *anonymous* constructor? This is not an anonymous class and so there is no need. Why not just use a constructor?

Comment: There could be several constructors. This is just an example. There are many ways to do that.